# Javascript end of For Loop chain a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, jquery-deferred

How do you go about knowing when a For Loop is done iterating and attach a callback.

This is a sample loop of many loops within a function that inserts records into *indexedDB*.

```
 if (Object.hasOwnProperty("Books")) {
            for (var i = 0, j = Object["Books"].length; i < j; i++) {
                server.Book.add({
                    title: Object["Books"][i].Cat,
                    content: Object["Books"][i]
                });
            }
        }
```

I need to be able to know when each of the if statements loops are finished then attach a callback. All the loops are being fired asynchronously, and I need to run a `function_final()` just when all loops are finished not when they are fired.

**EDIT**

What I have tried so far :

```
 InsertDB = {
  addBook: function(Object) {
    return $.Deferred(function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty("Book")) {                
            for (var i = 0, j = Object["Book"].length; i < j; i++) {
                server.Book.add({
                    title: Object["Book"][i].id,
                    content: Object["Book"][i]
                });
            }
            self.resolve();
        }
        }, 200);
   });  
 },
  addMagaz: function(Object) {
  return $.Deferred(function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {

        if (Object.hasOwnProperty("Magaz")) {
            for (var i = 0, j = Object["Magaz"].length; i < j; i++) {                  
                server.Magaz.add({
                    content: Object["Magaz"][i]
                });
            }
            self.resolve();
        }
        }, 2000);
   });  
},
addHgh: function(Object) {
    return $.Deferred(function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {

        if (Object.hasOwnProperty("MYTVhighlights")) {
            for (var i = 0, j = Object["MYTVhighlights"].length; i < j; i++) {
                server.MYTVhighlights.add({
                    content: Object["MYTVhighlights"][i]
                });
            }
            self.resolve();
         }
        }, 200);
   });  

  }, ect...
```

then on a AJAX success callback :

```
 success: function(data){
 var Object = $.parseJSON(data);

    $.when(InsertDB.addBook(Object),
    InsertDB.addMagaz(Object),
    InsertDB.addUser(Object),
    InsertDB.addArticles(Object),
    InsertDB.addHgh(Object),
    InsertDB.addSomeC(Object),
    InsertDB.addOtherC(Object)).done(final_func);

 function final_func() {
    window.location = 'page.html';
  }
```

Here final_func is fired before looping ends..

Thanks

Comment: Does server.Book.add return a promise?

Comment: I think that is exactly a task fo js Promise. Create promises for your loops. Resolve once loop is finished. Wrap promises in when. Attach single callback in then.

Comment: Yes it does. It is a IndexedDB plugin called DB.js and you can attach a .done().  Please see updated post, added what I have tried

Comment: If `server.Book.add()` is an asynchronous operation, how do you know when it's done?  Does it return a promise?  Does it have an option for a completion/success callback?  Without that information, you can't know when they are all done.

Comment: As a side note, it's a really bad practice to define your own variable named `Object` as that conflicts with the built-in `Object` definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've said that `server.Book.add()` is asynchronous, you will need a method of knowing when that asynchronous operation is completed and you can then use that to build a system for knowing when all of them are done.  So, the pivotal question (which I already asked as a comment earlier and you have not responded to) is how you can know when `server.Book.add()` is actually complete.  If you're using an `indexedDB`, then somewhere inside that function, there is probably a request object that has an `onsuccess` and `onerror` methods that will tell you when that specific operation is done and that information needs to get surfaced out to `server.Book.add()` in some way, either as a completion callback or as a returned promise (those two options are how `$.ajax()` operates for it's asynchronous behavior.

Let's suppose that `server.Book.add()` returns a promise object that is resolved or rejected when the asychronous `.add()` operation is complete.  If that was the case, then you could monitor the completion of all the operations in your loop like this:

```
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty("Books")) {
        var promises = [], p;

        for (var i = 0, j = obj["Books"].length; i < j; i++) {
            p = server.Book.add({
                title: obj["Books"][i].Cat,
                content: obj["Books"][i]
            });
            promises.push(p);
        }
        $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
            // this is executed when all the promises returned by
            // server.Book.add() have been resolved (e.g. completed)
        }).error(function() {
            // this is executed if any of the server.Book.add() calls
            // had an error
        });
    }
```

Let's suppose that instead of `server.Book.add()` returning a promise, it has a couple callbacks for `success` and `error` conditions.  Then, we could write the code like this:

```
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty("Books")) {
        var promises = [], p;

        for (var i = 0, j = obj["Books"].length; i < j; i++) {
            (function() {
                var d = $.Deferred();
                server.Book.add({
                    title: obj["Books"][i].Cat,
                    content: obj["Books"][i],
                    success: function() {
                        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
                        d.resolve.apply(d, args);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
                        d.reject.apply(d, args);
                    }
                });
                promises.push(d.promise());
            })();
        }
        $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
            // this is executed when all the promises returned by
            // server.Book.add() have been resolved (e.g. completed)
        }).error(function() {
            // this is executed if any of the server.Book.add() calls
            // had an error
        });
    }
```

So, since you've not disclosed how `server.Book.add()` actually indicates its own completion, I can't say that either of these blocks of code work as is.  This is meant to demonstrate how you solve this problem once you know how `server.Book.add()` communicates when it is complete.

Promises/Deferreds are not magic in any way.  They don't know when an operation is completed unless that operation calls `.resolve()` or `.reject()` on a promise.  So, in order to use promises, your async operations have to participate in using promises or you have to shim in a promise to an ordinary completion callback (as I've done in the second code block).

FYI, I also change your `Object` variable to `obj` because defining a variable named `Object` that conflicts with the built-in `Object` in the javascript language is a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you alot bro. I came up with something very close with the logic but not as well written.I tried to set up a counter for each iteration to be compared against the object's lenght.  this is a great help. Thanks again

Comment: server.book uses DB.js which is a wrapper for indexedDB http://aaronpowell.github.io/db.js/

Comment: Counters can be used too.  That's what `$.when()` has inside it and what we all did before we had promises.

Comment: I am still new to promises and callbacks. I need to dig deeper into it, but I think i get the drift.

Comment: What Does the error an Object could not be cloned ? in Node webkit. I keep getting this error while trying to insert records

Comment: @user3003977 - You'd have to show me exactly what line that error occurs on.  As I've said a couple times, you should NOT be using a variable named `Object` since that conflicts with the built-in `Object` in javascript.  That could be a source of your problem.

Comment: Again, +1!! I renamed my Object but it is not the issue, error is generated within db.js plugin in a deferred function. I am adopting the first example and all functions run synchronously without a problem. thanks a lot for your patience & advise

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript `closures`, just like this:

```
if (Object.hasOwnProperty("Books")) {
    for (var i = 0, j = Object["Books"].length; i < j; i++) {
        (function(currentBook)
            server.Book.add({
                title: currentBook.Cat,
                content: currentBook
            });
        )(Object["Books"][i]);
    }

    function_final();
}
```

For more information about `closures` you can refer [here](http://www.matteoagosti.com/blog/2012/09/03/how-to-properly-deal-with-javascript-asynchronous-code/).

Comment: This is a very informative article. It did not solve my problem. but thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery when functionality

```
$.when( function1 , function2 )
  .then( myFunc, myFailure );
```

Comment: This is basically a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write something like this in pure JS, consider it as pseudo code:

```
var totalForLoopsCount = 3; //Predict for loops count here
var forLoopsFinished = 0;

function finalFunction()
{
    alert('All done!');
}

function forLoopFinished()
{
    forLoopsFinished++;
    if(forLoopsFinished == totalForLoopsCount)
    {
        finalFunction();
    }
}

var length = 10; //The length of your array which you're iterating trough

for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    //Do anything        

    if(i == length-1)
    {
        forLoopFinished();
    }
}

for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    //Do anything        

    if(i == length-1)
    {
        forLoopFinished();
    }
}

for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    //Do anything    

    if(i == length-1)
    {
        forLoopFinished();
    }
}
```